WooCommerce remove "You are currently checking out as a guest"-text
In the woocommerce checkout page there is a section for quick-checkout without creating a user. It has this text "You are currently checking out as a guest.". I am trying to translate or remove it but I can't do neither.
What I have tried:
I have tried translating it via Loco Translate but it adding a translation for it won't be applied. I can translate all other text on the checkout page but just not that specific text.
I have also tried using a snippet to remove it like so, but it seems to have no effect:
add_filter('gettext', 'remove_guest_checkout_message', 20, 3);
function remove_guest_checkout_message($translated_text, $text, $domain) {
    if ($text === 'You are currently checking out as a guest') {
        $translated_text = ''; // Set to an empty string to remove the text
    }
    return $translated_text;
}

How can I get rid of this text or translate it?

It will be Returns empty string instead of default message
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', 'remove_guest_checkout_message' );
function remove_guest_checkout_message() {
    return ''; 
}

